# Milvus standalone configuration with a PersistentVolumeClaim

Tags: kubernetes, milvus

I am planning on deploying Milvus standalone on our Kubernetes cluster using the helm chart. Here is what I have as the command to do that:

```
helm install milvus-release milvus/milvus 
 --namespace ingress-basic 
 --set cluster.enabled=false 
 --set etcd.replicaCount=1 
 --set minio.mode=standalone 
 --set pulsar.enabled=false
 --set log.persistence.enabled=true 
 --set log.persistence.persistentVolumeClaim.existingClaim=<>
 --set standalone.nodeSelector."node.kubernetes.io/instance"=milvus
 --set standalone.persistence.enabled=true 
 --set standalone.persistence.persistentVolumeClaim.existingClaim=<>
```

Do I need to specify a PVC for Minio and Etcd separately, or setting  standalone.persistence.persistentVolumeClaim.existingClaim takes care of all data persistence for both of them as well?

A related question is that the node that I am deploying Milvus standalone on has an external IP assigned to it. In that case, do I need to set "service.type" to LoadBalancer to obtain an external IP?